# iOS Core Data Fetch Request, how to use

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am using Core Data to see whether messages in a table view have been seen before by the user. The way I do this is to save the message Id to Core Data the first time it is seen, and then I run a fetch request when I update the table view to see if there is an entry in the persistent memory with the same Id. 
Now what I want to know is how I should most effectively implement my fetch request, based on how time consuming it is. Should I either run a request that returns all saved message Ids as an array when the view is loaded, and then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`check if that array contains that cell's message Id, or run the fetch request with a predicate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? The latter would be my preferred method, but If i have 100 or so cells I wondered if this would be poor etiquette.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

This is my fetch Request :

```
func persistQuery(predicateValueString: String!) -> Bool! {

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "LogItem")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemText == %@", predicateValueString)

fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

var didFindResult = true

if let fetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [LogItem] {

    if fetchResults.count == 0 {
        didFindResult=false
    }
}

return didFindResult
```

}

Comment: Try both of your options and profile them to see which is best (and generally don't worry about it unless you observe a problem when testing under expected conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use a `NSFetchedResultsController`. It will optimize the fetching and the memory footprint as well. It is specifically designed for table views.

To get started, take a look at the Xcode template (Master/Detail, check Core Data). It is really quite simple.

Make sure you also implement the delegate methods - they will automatically be called when your managed objects change, so there is only minimal code that is executed to update the UI (an only if the object is actually on screen).

Presumably each of your table view cells represent a `LogItem` (the NSManagedObject subclass) with a property to indicate the `read` status. Once you change that, the delegate method will try to update it based on the index path.

That's all there is to it. With the fetched results controller you get a lot of optimization for free, so I would strongly recommend using it whenever you populate a table view with Core Data entities.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response, however I am not actually using the stored data to populate the table. The data source comes from our backend, but to keep my server requests low I store a read status on the device itself

Comment: I see. You should definitely store the data to be displayed in the device rather than just in memory. The above scheme is appropriate. You anyway parse the entire text of the message. Maybe if you just had ids you could reduce it, but UX would most likely be better if you could persist the data locally.